# How to target router-link-active class in element?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have a component with 2 router links. I want `both` to be colored when either one is clicked. Problem is that these router links don't share a `router-link-active` class, so I'm trying to target them via `querySelector` and apply the `color` css property manually.

This is the component:

```
<template>
  <div id="nav-link-cms" class="nav-link-cms">
    <li>
      <router-link class="router-link" :to="{ name: link}">
      <span>
        <fa class="icon" :icon="icon"></fa>
        <span class="label">{{ label }}</span>
        <router-link class="plus-link" v-if="plusLink" :to="{ name: plusLink }">
          <fa class="icon-plus" :icon="[ 'fas', 'circle-plus' ]"></fa>
        </router-link>
      </span>
      </router-link>
    </li>
  </div>
</template>
```

and I can target one router-link class `plus-link` like so:

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';

onMounted(() => {
    console.log(document.querySelector('.plus-link'))
})
</script>
```

This seems to work fine. The browser console outputs:

[image]

As you can see both `router-link-active` and `plus-link` classes are present in the link element.

Outputting the `classList` like so:

```
onMounted(() => {
    console.log(document.querySelector('.plus-link').classList)
})
```

shows this in the console:

```
DOMTokenList ['plus-link', value: 'plus-link']
0: "router-link-active"
1: "router-link-exact-active"
2: "plus-link"
length: 3
value: "router-link-active router-link-exact-active plus-link"
[[Prototype]]: DOMTokenList
```

But as soon as I try to see if the list `contains` a the `router-link-active` class:

```
onMounted(() => {
    console.log(document.querySelector('.plus-link').classList.contains('router-link-active'))
})
```

the console shows:

```
false
```

Is `router-link-active` applied even after `onMounted`? How can I target it?

Comment: A more 'Vue' approach instead of using querySelectors, could be to create a new data property called 'styleActiveRoute: false', and the watch the $route(to,from). If you navigate to one of these routes, then set the styleActiveRoute to true, and if it is not one of these routes then false... and then bind styleActiveRoute as a class using :class="styleActiveRoute" on your router-link. Finally, add a .styleActiveRoute: {  color: red }

Answer (score 2):

Have not tried it myself but you should be able to use `useLink` [Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#uselink), from Vue-Router to get if the value for each route (`link` and `plusLink`), and then look at the `isActive` property of both of them then pass it to the template.

Psudo-code:

```
<template>
 <router-link :class="{active: isActive}" :to="link">
  <router-link :to="plusLink"></router-link>
 </router-link>
</template>
```

```
<script setup>
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from "vue-router";
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useLink } from "vue-router";

const isActive = ref(false);
const linkState = useLink({ to: "about" });
const linkPlusState = useLink({ to: "new" });
watch([linkState.isActive + linkPlusState.isActive], () => {
  if (linkState.isActive || linkPlusState.isActive) {
    isActive.value = true;
  } else {
    isActive.value = false;
  }
});
</script>
```

Note: As a general thing you should avoid direct DOM manipulation when using any FE framework.

Comment: I've tried your approach but end up getting an undefined link in `const linkPlusState = useLink({to: linkPlus})`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Updated to use a watcher and test in a new Vue project, please try.